# Trying to create REST-ful URLs with multiple dots in the "filename" part - Spring 3.0 MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC (3.0) with annotation-driven controllers. I would like to create REST-ful URLs for resources and be able to **not** require (but still optionally allow) file extension on the end of the URL (but assume HTML content type if no extension). This works out-of-the-box with Spring MVC as long as there are no dots (period/full-stop) in the filename part.

However some of my URLs require an identifier with dots in the name. E.g. like this:

```
http://company.com/widgets/123.456.789.500
```

In this case Spring looks for a content type for the extension `.500` and finds none so errors. I can use work-arounds like adding `.html` to the end, encoding the identifier or adding a trailing slash. I'm not happy with any if these but could probably live with adding `.html`.

I've unsuccessfully looked for a way of overriding the default file extension detection in Spring.

Is it possible to customize or disable file extension detection for a given controller method or URL pattern, etc?

Comment: How can I implement that if Im not using rest?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75861750/java-rest-assured-url-with-multiple-dots-over-time-error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `@PathVariable` pattern matching is a bit twitchy when it comes to dots in the URL (see [SPR-5778](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5778)). You can make it less twitchy (but more picky), and get better control over dot-heavy URLs, by setting the [`useDefaultSuffixPattern`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html#setUseDefaultSuffixPattern%28boolean%29) property on [`DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html) to `false`.

If you haven't already explicitly declared a `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` in your context (and most people don't since it's declared implicitly for you), then you can add it explicitly, and set that property.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks Skaffman. But it broke another part of the app... the contentNegotiatingViewResolver which maps a ".json" extension to Jackson no longer works. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Sorted the problem with contentNegotiatingViewResolver by explicitly associating my controller method with the URL including the ".json". E.g. using the annotation: @RequestMapping(value = "/search.json", method = RequestMethod.GET). Is there a nicer solution to this?

Comment: > Have you tried @RequestMapping(value = "/search*")

Thanks again skaffman, that is a better solution.

Comment: Adding RegEx solves the problem  `@RequestMapping(path = "{employeeId}/profilePicture/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Answer (score 12):

Probably, it's an ugly hack, I just wanted to explore extensibility of Spring @MVC. Here is a customized `PathMatcher`. It uses `$` in the pattern as the end marker - if pattern ends with it, marker is removed and pattern is matched by the default matcher, but if pattern has `$` in the middle (e.g. `...$.*`), such a pattern is not matched.

```
public class CustomPathMatcher implements PathMatcher {
    private PathMatcher target;

    public CustomPathMatcher() {
        target = new AntPathMatcher();
    }

    public String combine(String pattern1, String pattern2) {
        return target.combine(pattern1, pattern2); 
    }

    public String extractPathWithinPattern(String pattern, String path) {
        if (isEncoded(pattern)) {
            pattern = resolvePattern(pattern);
            if (pattern == null) return "";
        }
        return target.extractPathWithinPattern(pattern, path);
    }

    public Map<String, String> extractUriTemplateVariables(String pattern,
            String path) {
        if (isEncoded(pattern)) {
            pattern = resolvePattern(pattern);
            if (pattern == null) return Collections.emptyMap();
        }
        return target.extractUriTemplateVariables(pattern, path);
    }

    public Comparator<String> getPatternComparator(String pattern) {
        final Comparator<String> targetComparator = target.getPatternComparator(pattern);
        return new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                if (isEncoded(o1)) {
                    if (isEncoded(o2)) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                } else if (isEncoded(o2)) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return targetComparator.compare(o1, o2);
            }        
        };
    }

    public boolean isPattern(String pattern) {
        if (isEncoded(pattern)) {
            pattern = resolvePattern(pattern);
            if (pattern == null) return true;
        }
        return target.isPattern(pattern);
    }

    public boolean match(String pattern, String path) {
        if (isEncoded(pattern)) {
            pattern = resolvePattern(pattern);
            if (pattern == null) return false;
        }
        return target.match(pattern, path);
    }

    public boolean matchStart(String pattern, String path) {
        if (isEncoded(pattern)) {
            pattern = resolvePattern(pattern);
            if (pattern == null) return false;
        }
        return target.match(pattern, path);
    }

    private boolean isEncoded(String pattern) {
        return pattern != null && pattern.contains("$");
    }

    private String resolvePattern(String pattern) {
        int i = pattern.indexOf('$');
        if (i < 0) return pattern;
        else if (i == pattern.length() - 1) {
            return pattern.substring(0, i);
        } else {
            String tail = pattern.substring(i + 1);
            if (tail.startsWith(".")) return null;
            else return pattern.substring(0, i) + tail;
        }
    }
}
```

Config:

```
<bean id = "pathMatcher" class = "sample.CustomPathMatcher" />

<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name = "pathMatcher" ref="pathMatcher" />
</bean>

<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name = "pathMatcher" ref="pathMatcher" />
</bean>
```

And usage (given "/hello/1.2.3", `value` is "1.2.3"):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{value}$", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String hello(@PathVariable("value") String value, ModelMap model)
```

**EDIT:**: Now doesn't break "trailing slash doesn't matter" rule

Comment: Thanks for this code - really useful.  Thought i'd mention to anyone else using this that you should remove <mvc:annotation-driven /> from your mvc config if adding the custom pathMatcher configuration above.

Answer (score 6):

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
```

`@Controller
public class MyController {
 @RequestMapping(value="/widgets/{preDot}.{postDot}")
 public void getResource(@PathVariable String preDot, @PathVariable String postDot) {
    String fullPath = preDot + "." + postDot;
    //...
 }
}`

// Above code should match /widgets/111.222.333.444

Answer (score 5):

Spring 3.2 has changed, and suggests that you set properties on the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean, either explicitly (if not using the mvc namespace) [or by using a BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-advanced-xml) such as the following (you'll need to scan or instantiate it):

```
@Component
public class IncludeExtensionsInRequestParamPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
            RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = (RequestMappingHandlerMapping)bean;
            mapping.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(false);
            mapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) { return bean; }
}
```

You can also just append `:.*` to your @RequestMapping, e.g. `"/{documentPath:.*}"` [(see JIRA comment)](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9333?focusedCommentId=77790&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-77790)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I also solved it by custom PathMatcher. My solution is somewhat simplier to what axtavt proposed. My PathMatcher also has a private final AntPathMatcher target, and it delegates all calls to it unchanged, except for match() method:

```
@Override
public boolean match(String pattern, String path) {
    return pattern.endsWith(".*") ? false : target.match(pattern, path);
}
```

This works because Spring tries to match controllers by adding ".*" to the end. For example, with path mapping "/widgets/{id}" and URL "/widgets/1.2.3.4", Spring tries first match againts "/widgets/{id}.*" and after that "/widgets/{id}". The first will match, but it leaves only "1.2.3" for id.

My PatchMatcher specifically rejects patterns ending ".*", thus the first attempt fails and the second matches.

If you are using ContentNegotiatingViewResolver you can still specify content type in URL's using request parameter "format" (if the favorParameter is set to true).

-jarppe

Answer (score 2):

JFY: in **Spring 4** this issue is fixed via: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Configuration 
class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
}
}
```

Or via WebMvcConfigurationSupport like [here](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2013/01/spring-mvc-customizing.html).

and in **Spring 5**:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to skaffman's answer, if you're using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and you want to override the useDefaultSuffixPattern value, you can replace the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag with the following:

```
<!-- Maps requests to @Controllers based on @RequestMapping("path") annotation values -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>

<!-- Enables annotated @Controllers -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```