# Controller arguments annotated with Spring 3 MVC PathParameter is stripping data after the last '.'

Tags: java, spring-mvc

When experimenting with Spring MVC, I noticed the values passed to controller arguments annotated with @PathVariable will have all the characters from the last '.' on stripped, unless the last character is a '/'.

For example, given the following code:

```
@RequestMapping("/host/${address})"
public String getHost(@PathVariable String address, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("host", hostRepository.getHost(address));
    return "host";
}
```

If the URL is "/host/127.0.0.1", the value of `address` will be "127.0.0".  If the URL is "/host/127.0.0.1/", the value of `address` will be "127.0.0.1".

Is there away to prevent this stripping?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079299/trying-to-create-rest-ful-urls-with-mulitple-dots-in-the-filename-part-spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of such reports in their issue tracker already (for example, [SPR-5778](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5778)). But they don't fix it, so it seems to be a legitimate behaviour.

The official workaround is to set `useDefaultSuffixPattern = false` on `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, but it has several drawbacks:

- It is applied to all controllers
- It completely disables extension handling (for example, for `ContentNegotiationViewResolver`)
- It breaks "trailing slash doesn't matter" rule

More sophisticated workarounds use a customized `PathMatcher`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079299/trying-to-create-rest-ful-urls-with-mulitple-dots-in-the-filename-part-spring/2081590).

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently been handled as a file extension and stripped. Not sure if it's a bug. I would fill an issue at [their issuetracker](http://jira.springframework.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

**Update**: please check this topic, it's actually not a bug and it can be solved programmatically: [Trying to create REST-ful URLs with mulitple dots in the “filename” part - Spring 3.0 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079299/trying-to-create-rest-ful-urls-with-mulitple-dots-in-the-filename-part-spring)

Comment: That was my thought, too; just wanted to see if anyone else had info.