# Dynamic URL special characters : @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am using Spring and Hibernate in my project.

Is there a way to handle dynamic URL(i.e. hyperlink which is populated dynamically depending on searchResult) through modelAttribute i.e. using a variable and passing same to controller just like passing input bean??

I am using @PathVariable for handling dynamic URL action from JSP to Controller. During the same if my dynamic URL contains combination of special characters like ./ then the URL is getting truncated.

Please help.

Comment: can u give me some example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC Getting PathVariables containing dots and slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516969/spring-mvc-getting-pathvariables-containing-dots-and-slashes)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you may be experiencing a similar problem with [Spring MVC Getting PathVariables containing dots and slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516969/spring-mvc-getting-pathvariables-containing-dots-and-slashes).

Where it was resolved by changing the url declaration where its attribute instead of `/{attribute}` added the value in the url as`/{atributo:.+}`