# Spring MVC path variable for the rest of path

Tags: spring-mvc

If request URIs I can get are `http://file/first_dir/second_dir/file.txt`, is there a way to put everything after `http://file` into a variable/method argument like it is possible with `@PathVariable` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a confusing URL, file is usually a protocol, so its easy to get confused. Anyways, the problem is that the path variable separator is set to "/" and you can't "beat" this with a regex inside a request mapping. So one way would be to go for a custom mapper, here's a DZone article describing a custom mapper for optional path variables

http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-webmvc-optional-path

But if I were you, I would give this solution a try, [Spring MVC Getting PathVariables containing dots and slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516969/spring-mvc-getting-pathvariables-containing-dots-and-slashes)
it uses a regex inside a rewrite filter to catch a sequence, and posts it as a parameter. I think it can provide a viable solution for you