# REST API URL with Directory and File name as Path Variables

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, restful-url

I have a requirement to send the folder details in the URL for POST method, some thing like this
http:///{directory}/{filename}

I am using Spring API to create the service. Using @PathVariables to two variables in the URI.

Problem : Directory can have "/" slashes in it. 
Now how can I create my API, please help me.

Comment: Why do you wanna send this information using URL? What if you send this information as a part of POST payload?

Comment: You can create or ask others to create payload like this.
{
    "directoryName" : "MyDir",
    "fileName" : "Its my new file"
}

Comment: This will give you some flexibility if you would like to extend/add some details to your REST API.

Comment: And your url will be: POST : http://{your web context}/files

Comment: @asg I try that and used JSONUtil to unMarshal that, but that is giving the problem. It is throwing an Exception saying "/" slash is not allowed.

Comment: Then you may want to ask that specific question with your exception, jars used etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516969/spring-mvc-getting-pathvariables-containing-dots-and-slashes

Comment: I managed it with the JSON input data.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST http://example.com/api/files/path/to/my/file/filename
```

Stick a controller on `/api/files`. Scrape the URL starting after `/files`. Use that to locate the file.

P.S. This has the potential to be a Very Bad Idea. Make sure you secure the controller to only expose those parts of your filesystem you don't mind random internet strangers to be able to operate on.

Comment: I think that might live some security issue. I try to remove those path variables and convert that as JSON object , but JSONUtil.unMarshall throwing an error because value have "/" slash in it