# Spring RequestMapping period

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring App, I have a controller annotated like so:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/1/site")
```

If I try to change the request mapping value to this, I get a 404:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/1.0/site")
```

What is happening with the period, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you explore issues such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079299/trying-to-create-rest-ful-urls-with-mulitple-dots-in-the-filename-part-sprin) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated)? It's likely due to extension handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dot has special meaning in URLs. I'd refrain from using it the way you intended. Use a dash or underscore instead. See [SPR-5778](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5778) for details.