# dot ('.') in URL is removed when executing Restclient

Tags: c#, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient, rest-client

I am using .net framework 4.0 together with Restsharp.

Executing the Restclient for 'normal' URL works fine. But sometimes the URL refers to URLs like 'https://somewhere@xyz.com/RA/and/9g9_AAABizUAAAFIrzQywzU./shipping' . In these cases the '.' in the URL (at the end of '9g9_AAABizUAAAFIrzQywzU.') is removed when the execute method is called. So the resource searched cannot be found.

Is there a workaround for this behaviour?

Comment: [Similar issue in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079299/trying-to-create-rest-ful-urls-with-mulitple-dots-in-the-filename-part-sprin) possibly related?

Comment: Upgrade to .NET4.5? See "trailing dot" section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The Upgrade to .NET4.5 solved this problem. Removing the trailing dots is a 'feature' of the previous frameworks.