# Spring RequestMapping wildcard and suffix

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request

I want to create a mapping for an URI like this.

> /reference/download/asdsa/asdas/sad/3c7d38f679a64d101c602da61dad9912.pdf

The request mapping in my controller is:

> /reference/download/**

The problem is, that the mapping is only working when I call the URI **without** the .pdf suffix.

This is my code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reference")
public class ReferenceFilePageController
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ReferenceFilePageController.class);

    private static final String PATH_VARIABLE_PATTERN_DOWNLOAD = "/download/**";

    @Autowired
    private ReferenceFileService referenceFileService;

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH_VARIABLE_PATTERN_DOWNLOAD, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileSystemResource getFile(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String path = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);

        return new FileSystemResource(referenceFileService.getPathForIdentifier(path.substring(19)));
    }

}
```

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079299/trying-to-create-rest-ful-urls-with-mulitple-dots-in-the-filename-part-sprin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [*Content Negotiation*](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc).

Comment: I removed "produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE" from the mapping. It's working now.